# Overloaded VB.NET extension method in class library

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, extension-methods

It seems that my library of extension methods that was written in VB.NET has problems.

I have 2 overloaded extension methods Crop().

When i reference the lib from a VB.NET project i see them. If reference it from a C# project i can't see them.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: Where the hell is the code?

Comment: VB or VB.NET? Tag [vb] stands for Visual Basic (versions 5, 6)

Comment: Plz test the scenario to see if you get the same problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this:

- In C#, when you call a method with an `out` or `ref` parameter, the compiler requires you to repeat the `out` or `ref` keyword on the calling argument. This is because it does matter to the language whether the variable is already initialised or not.
- In VB.NET, when you call a method with a `ByRef` parameter, the compiler does not require you to repeat `ByRef` on the calling argument, it just sorts it out for you. This is because it does not matter to the language whether the variable is already initialised or not.

Therefore, VB.NET can easily resolve an extension method using `ByRef`, because there is only one possible way in which it can be called. However, C# does not know what to do because there is no syntax for telling it whether to call the method using `out` or `ref`.

All you can do is:

- Re-write your extension methods to use a `ByVal` parameter wherever possible.
- If that is not possible, then you are stuck with calling them from C# like normal methods.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, my guess is that you're missing a `using` statement in your C# .cs file.

```
//other usings...

//Extension using statement...
using MyAssembly.Extensions;

class Program {
  static void Main() {
    //some code
    String myString = "blah";

    //call the extension method now
    String newString = myString.MyExtensionMethod();
  }
}
```

But this is just a guess without seeing your code.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

My methods were using byref arguments. I changed it to byval and it worked.

It's very weird apparently. In VB projects its ok but in C# not. Apparently C# does not support extension methods with byref or it is a bug.

Comment: Did you use the ref keyword when you called the method from c#?